# WrongTypeOfReturnValue exception thrown when unit testing using mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, tdd, mockito

**My Test**

```
List<Person> myList;

@Test
public void testIsValidPerson() {
    myList = new ArrayList<Person>();

    myList.add(new Person("Tom"));
    when(personDao.get(person)).thenReturn(myList);
    when((personDao.get(person)).isEmpty()).thenReturn(false);//------Exception thrown 

    boolean result = service.isValid("Tom");
    assertFalse(result);
}
```

**Method to be tested:**

```
public boolean isValid(String person){
    personDao = new PersonDao();
    Person personObj = new Person(person);
    return (personDao.get(person).isEmpty())?false : true;      
}
```

**Exception thrown:**

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Boolean cannot be returned by get()
get() should return List
***
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.
```

**My Second approach using spy:**

```
public void testIsValidPerson() {
    myList = new ArrayList<Person>();

    myList.add(new Person("Tom"));
    when(personDao.get(person)).thenReturn(myList);

    List<Person> mylist = personDao.get(person);
    List spy = spy(mylist);

    doReturn(false).when(spy.isEmpty());//------exception thrown

    boolean result = service.isValid("Tom");
    assertFalse(result);
}
```

This gives me the following exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.PersonTest.testIsValid(PersonTest.java:76)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
```

**Third appraoch:**

```
@Test
public void testIsValidPerson() {
    myList = new ArrayList<Person>();

    myList.add(new Person("Tom"));
    when(personDao.get(person)).thenReturn(myList);

    boolean result = service.isValid("Tom");//--------Throws null pointer exception
    assertFalse(result);
}

public boolean isValid(String person){
    personDao = new PersonDao();
    Person personObj = new Person(person);
    return (personDao.get(person).isEmpty())?false : true;  //----throws NPE    
}
```

**Fourth Approach:** throws Null pointer exception

```
@Test
public void testIsValidPerson() {
    List<Person> mockedList = mock(List.class);
    when(personDao.get(person)).thenReturn(mockedList);
    when(personDao.get(person)).isEmpty().thenReturn(false);
    boolean result = service.isValid("Tom");//--------Throws null pointer exception
    assertFalse(result);
}

public boolean isValid(String person){
    personDao = new PersonDao();
    Person personObj = new Person(person);
    return (personDao.get(person).isEmpty())?false : true;  //----throws NPE    
}
```

**Fifth approach:** Also gives NPE.

The get method of personDao accesses the database and the NPE is thrown when getting a connection to the DB. But it doesn't give NPE the first time around when I get an empty list back. I get NPE in the second call from `service.isValid()`

```
@Test
public void testIsValidPerson() {
    when(personDao.get(person)).thenReturn(new ArrayList<Person>());
    List tempList=personDao.get(person);//----I get empty tempList---No NPE
    boolean result = service.isValid("Tom");//--------Throws null pointer exception
    assertFalse(result);
}
```

**Approach 6:**

```
@Test
public void testIsValid() {
    personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
    Person person = new Person("Tom");
    personList.add(person);
    when(personDao.get(person)).thenReturn(personList);//-------Uses same person object

    boolean result = service.isValid(person);//------------Uses same person object
    assertTrue(result);
}
```

And I changed my method signature from(so that the test and the method under test would use the same value).

```
public boolean isValid(String name)
```

to

```
public boolean isValid(Person person)
```

Comment: Why do you want to mock or spy an ArrayList? You created a list. It contains a person named Tom. So calling isEmpty() on the list will return false. No need to mock or spy anything to have isEmpty() return false. The mocked DAO returns the list containing Tom. The service calls the mocked DAO and thus gets the list containing Tom. No need to mock anything else.

Comment: @JBNizet I have edited my post, Third approach section in my post. If that is what you mean, I get NPE when I do that.

Comment: You get NPE because the service doesn't use the mock DAO that you have created and stubbed in your test. It creates a brand new PersonDao. You need to pass the mock DAO as a parameter of the constructor of the service. In short, you need to use dependency injection.

Comment: Susie, I'm a bit confused as to what you're asking, and what you'd want from an answer now.  You have posted six different code snippets - do they all give you a Null Pointer Exception?  Are you satisfied with my explanation of why the fifth approach doesn't work?  And what happens with the sixth approach?  It seems to me that it would probably work, although I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you do not have enough mocks.
You are attempting to mock an `isEmpty` method of a `List` returned by a mock object. You have a mock object, but you do not make the mock object return a mock list so you could mock the methods of a mock list ...

One thing I fail to understand though is why are you attempting to make a list that has elements, but returns true for `isEmpty`

If you need to test how your code behaves when it gets an empty list, just make an empty list. This way `isEmpty` will automatically return false.

```
when(personDao.get(person)).thenReturn(new ArrayList<Person>());
```

Comment: I mocked the returned list in my 4th approach section in my post and this time I get NPE.

Comment: Yeah, don't mock the list.  It's a value object.  Too many bad things happen when you mock things like lists.

Comment: In this case, your NPE is probably because the `person` String passed into `isValid` isn't the same as the `person` value (presumably from a field) that is in scope during `testIsValid`.

Comment: @DavidWallace I tried without mocking the list like anttix suggested and then calling ` personDao.isValid()` and I still get NPE.

Comment: So in this fifth scenario that you're describing, what does `personDao.get(person)` return?

Comment: @DavidWallace It returns an empty list.

Comment: And you still get an NPE when you call `isEmpty()`?  That's a bit odd.  Maybe you can add this fifth scenario to your question, because I have a feeling that there's something  you haven't told me.

Comment: @DavidWallace I added the fifth scenario in my post.

Comment: As I said a little while ago, this is happening because the `person` String passed into `isValid` (which is `"Tom"`) isn't the same as the `person` value (presumably from a field) that is in scope during `testIsValid`.  So you're stubbing with one value, then running with another.

Comment: @DavidWallace the first call to the personDao.get(..) works fine and returns an empty list but gives NPE when service.isValid() is called. service.isValid() method also calls personDao.get(..). Please refer to my fifth approach for more details.

Comment: Yes, but you stubbed it for a particular value of `person`, then ran it with a different value of `person`.

Comment: I was able to run the test. But like you said it uses different value of person. I was able to run it successfully by changing the method signature in my approach 6 in my post above. But can I not do it without changing method signature?

Comment: No, of course you don't have to change the method signature.  But you are stubbing the method call for _one_ value of `person`, then passing a _different_ value to the method.  You're telling Mockito "smile when you see Susie", then showing it Tom and wondering why it's not smiling.

Answer (score 1):

The line `when((personDao.get(person)).isEmpty()).thenReturn(false);` makes no sense, because `personDao.get(person)` isn't a mock.  It's just `myList`, because you stubbed it that way on the line above.  So this is exactly the same as doing `when(myList.isEmpty()).thenReturn(false);` - but you can't stub this because there's no mock here.

Comment: I mocked the returned list in my 4th approach section in my post and this time I get NPE.